# How do I reference existing objects from Spring.NET configuration?

Tags: spring.net

This question is in regard to the dependency injection feature of Spring.NET.  Assume that I have the following object dependencies:

A depends on B (via the property A.B), and B depends on C (via the property B.C)

In my Spring.NET configuration I can define objects A, B, and C, and use "ref" to wire up the A.B and B.C properties.

Now, assume that I already have an instance of C that I would like to use.  Is there a way to have Spring.NET construct A and B from the configuration, but use the existing C?  Ideally I would like for Spring.NET to skip the construction of a new C object, and set the B.C property to the existing C instance automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you already have an instance of C, you can register that instance under a given name.

```
((IConfigurableApplicationContext) context).ObjectFactory.RegisterSingleton("C", cInstance);
```